# Cassandra bulk loader to load from compressed CSV files

Tags: amazon-s3, cassandra, bulk-load

Is there a way to use Cassandra bulk-loading solutions (e.g. COPY) to load from **zipped** CSV files without having to unzip them?

I have 48GB compressed data in Amazon S3 that I need to load to Cassandra. The resources/disk storage aren't such that I can download this amount of data unzip it and then load to Cassandra.

Comment: Is it one big csv file in the zip or multiple small files?

Comment: The csv is in multiple parts, independently zipped.